# Backed up application doesn't work

Tags: iis

I have two servers with IIS 7 installed and configured. Call those servers web1 and web2, for example. My task was to backup a site called "site1" from web1 to web2. The task was completed, but now when I'm opening site1, I recieve this errors stack:

```
Exception information: System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractException: Statement error: primitiveType != null

    Stacktrace: 


    [ContractException: Ошибка в утверждении: primitiveType != null]
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ContractHelper.TriggerFailureImplementation(ContractFailureKind kind, String displayMessage, String userMessage, String conditionText, Exception innerException) +5643014
       System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.RuntimeFailureMethods.ReportFailure(ContractFailureKind contractFailureKind, String userMessage, String conditionText, Exception innerException) +298
       System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.TypeExtensions..cctor() +169

    [TypeInitializationException: Инициализатор типа "System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.TypeExtensions" выдал исключение.]
       System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.TypeExtensions.IsValidStructuralType(Type type) +0
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbSetDiscoveryService.GetSets() +528
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbSetDiscoveryService.InitializeSets() +24
       DomainModel.Concrete.SqlPageRepository..ctor(String connectionString) +36

    [TargetInvocationException: Адресат вызова создал исключение.]
       System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
       System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +662
       Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Object[] arguments, Type[] signature) +322

    [ComponentActivatorException: ComponentActivator: could not instantiate DomainModel.Concrete.SqlPageRepository]
       Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Object[] arguments, Type[] signature) +586
       Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context) +82
       Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context) +29
       Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context) +23
       Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context) +133
       Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context) +102
       Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver parentResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) +749
       Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate constructor, CreationContext context, Type[]& signature) +337
       Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context) +60
       Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context) +29
       Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context) +23
       Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context) +102
       Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments) +46
       WebUI.WindsorControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +25
       System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +81
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +280
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +80
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +19
       System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +128
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12288259
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

And I have absolutely no idea how to fix it in IIS, not in code. If you have any ideas, help me, please! :c

Comment: How much do you know about the application?  Do you have RDP access to both machines? How did you take a backup?  Sounds like a dependency is failing to load. If you can you access both machines for comparison, take a look at the machine.config files for server level IIS config (modules, handlers etc). Compare add/remove programs lists (missing database libraries / other things your application may use). If your really in the dark about how it works/what its doing, use ProcMon from SysInternals and filter by processes called w3p.exe and recycle the app to see what files/registry keys its using

Comment: I know what is this application for. I haven't seen the code or the development process. I have RDP access to both of them. I took a backup using the Microsoft Web Deploy V3 application (msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:apphostconfig="site1" -dest:package="site2.zip"). And I've restored the backup using the same command, but in another direction (msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package="site2.zip" -dest:apphostconfig="site2").